# How do I write a Logary target for my .NET application?

Tags: f#, logary

I am trying to get started with Logary. I need to write a new target and I have tried following the following tutorial https://logary.tech/tutorials. I have downloaded Logary.sln from https://github.com/logary/logary, but I am not able to build Logary.sln. When I build it I get 40 errors and all of them say: The command ""paket.exe" restore" exited with code 9009.

When I try to add the nuget Logary (latest 5.0) with NuGet manager I get NU1108: Cycle detected. Logary -> Logary (>= 5.0.0).

When I try following this https://logary.tech/logary-dotnet-quickstart I get 2 errors as well.

So, I am totally lost. What am I missing out? I will provide more information if necessary. I want to write a target in F# for my .NET application that would be sent as an event to Logary's centralised event storage.

Comment: Looks like an issue with the logary package.  I would file an issue with the project.

Comment: Unless you named your project "Logary" too?  In which case, name it something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used FAKE build and it worked OK. The problem was cause by some namespaces, which is fixed in the fake.

Answer (score 0):

I seems that the problem is with the project name. Its name is the same as the referenced NuGet package. So to resolve this problem you should changed the project name and the build will succeeded.